# HTML onclick function not working for a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

So I'm making a website, and I have some buttons that scroll to certain parts of a page. I have 5 buttons, and all of them have the exact same code except for their names. One of the buttons is broken and doesn't do anything, even though its code is the same as the working ones.

Here is my HTML:

About Us

```
    <div class = "OurMethodsBar">
        <button class = "OurMethodsButton" onclick = "ScrollTo(OurMethodsAnchor)">
            Our Methods
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class = "InvestBar">
        <button class = "InvestButton" onclick = "ScrollTo(InvestAnchor)">
                Invest
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class = "ContactUsBar">
        <button class = "ContactUsButton" onlclick = "ScrollTo(ContactUsAnchor)">
            Contact Us
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class = "MoreInformationBar">
        <button class = "MoreInformationButton" onclick = "ScrollTo(MoreInfoAnchor)">
            More Info
        </button>
    </div>
```

Here is my JS:

var AboutUsAnchor = document.getElementById("AboutUsAnchor");

```
var OurMethodsAnchor = document.getElementById("OurMethodsAnchor");
var InvestAnchor = document.getElementById("InvestAnchor");
var ContactUsAnchor = document.getElementById("ContactUsAnchor");
var MoreInfoAnchor = document.getElementById("MoreInfoAnchor");

function ScrollTo(Element) {
    Element.scrollIntoView(true);
}

ScrollTo(AboutUsAnchor);
```

The broken button is the ContactUsButton which is supposed to scroll to the ContactUsAnchor.
If I manually use my ScrollTo function and input the ContactUsAnchor, it still works, but when I try to hit the button, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi! You misspelled `onclick` to `onlclick`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather change approach and rewrite your function to get a string and get the element by ID later.

```
function ScrollTo(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

And then in your buttons just pass the string containing the ID in single quotes `'`

```
    <button class = "ContactUsButton" onclick = "ScrollTo('ContactUsAnchor')">
        Contact Us
    </button>
```

And as others have pointed out, fix that `onlclick` :P

Comment: Thankee, I didn't see the typo